# Wrong dendrogram generated

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, hierarchical-clustering, linkage, dendrogram

I have 31 data, but `dendrogram` is missing one data. Here is my code:

```
A = csvread('similarityNoGrpS2.csv',1,1) % 31x31 double
Z = linkage(A, 'average') % 30x3 double
H = dendrogram(Z,'Orientation','left','ColorThreshold','default') %29x1 line
```

My input file can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw5odYicN9U5VzNyZDFlZS03NDg).

Here is my `dendrogram`:

[image: output]

According to `Z`, `(24,30)` and `(27,31)` should be clustered, but in `dendrogram` pic, we can see there is no `31` and `27` is getting clustered with `30` which is wrong!

Can anyone help me in this matter?

P.S. I'm using MATLAB R2016a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the last line of your code to this:

```
H = dendrogram(Z, 0, 'Orientation', 'left', 'ColorThreshold', 'default');
```

which for the given data gives:

[image]

---

### Explanation

Your ***original data set*** (`A`) has more than `30` points but you did not specify the value of `P`. It is mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dendrogram.html#btk0xou-2):

> If you do not specify `P` then `dendrogram` uses 30 as the maximum number of leaf nodes. ***To display the complete tree, set `P` equal to `0`***.

So you need to put `P=0` in this syntax:

```
dendrogram(tree,P,Name,Value)
```

Comment: @user3701435 Happy to help!